# Constructor invokes Other Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm fairly new to cpp so I apologize if this is a stupid question. I have created a class and want it to include in another class I've made. When I created the constructor for the above class it creates a subclass variable however it seems to be trying to call the default constructor for the sub class, which I don't have one. Is there a way to setup the variable without calling a constructor?

game.hpp

```
class Game {
  private:
    char players[2];
    char curPlayer;
    TTTBoard<TTTBoard<char>> board; <-------
    int curBoard[2];
    int nextBoard[2];
    bool finished;

  public:
    Game();
    const bool isFinished() const;
    const char getCurPlayer() const;
    const char next();
    void setCurBoard(int x, int y);
    void printWholeBoard();
    void printCurBoard();
    void setPos(int x, int y);
};
```

I think this is what is happening because when I try to compile I get the following error

```
game.cpp:3:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘TTTBoard<TTTBoard<char> >::TTTBoard()’ Game::Game(void) {
```

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's calling a default constructor. No, you have not defined it. You are not constructing something correctly. Unfortunately, you failed to show your actual constructors, and all relevant class declarations. As such, no answer is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default constructor of `TTTBoard<TTTBoard<char>>` will be called here. If it doesn't have one, you need to use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) to specify the appropriate constructor to initialize the member `board` in the implemention the constructor of `Game`.

> Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified.

e.g.

```
class Game {
  private:
    TTTBoard<TTTBoard<char>> board;

  public:
    Game() : board(some_arguments) {}
    //     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
};
```